# How to parse information from any website?

Tags: c#, parsing, windows-phone-7

http://www.eyecinema.ie/cinemas/home.asp?ci=2&ln=1

I want to get the movie times for all films from this website...my question is not just for this website but I'm using this as an example.

I've done some xml parsing and managed to create an RSS reader which is up on the marketplace but now I am trying to create a new app but my problem is, I want to be able to scrape information from any website for particular information. Such as cinema times from the above website...

How do I go about doing this?? 
Any help would be appreciated, greatly.

Comment: You might want to read the Terms & Conditions of that site.  In particular Item 1. which specifically says you aren't allowed to do this: http://www.eyecinema.ie/cinemas/terms_and_conditions.asp?SessionID=5F1A6AC768514ED88334EB973D079DBF&cn=1&ci=2&ln=1

Comment: Further: MOST sites have similar terms.  If you do this, especially for the purpose of aggregating that information into an app you are making available on a marketplace then you are opening yourself up to some serious legal issues.  This is a side issue to your question, but one that you really need to explore before you land in jail over it.

Comment: Oh, never thought about the copyright issues. Thank you for the comment. There goes my app idea out the window. I would still like to know how you would do this, however? Not this website, but some such the Eclipse.org which as far as I know is Open Source...

Comment: @NoGimmicks: so you need to parse cinemas site and eclipse site? Do you really think anyone believes that?

Comment: @zerkms No thats not what I mean...I just gave it as an example. I would like to be able to parse information from a website despite my problems with the earlier idea.

Answer (score 2):

There is no magic bullet. Each website is likely to have a distinct way of formatting the required information into HTML, and you'll have to write a distinct parser for each site. From time to time, each website will change its format without warning, and then you'll have to put out a fire and rewrite the parser for that site.